# Keeping Images Centered As New Pictures Are Added with CSS in Ionic Project

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm very new to coding and need some help with image alignment using CSS. The program needs to take pictures and each time it takes a picture, a thumbnail of the picture needs to be added in line. Using 'margin: auto' I'm able to get them to stay centered each time a picture is added. However I need to have each of the thumbnails remain as centered as possible, removing the large gap that occurs when they line up.

[Screenshot of CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i10TF.png)

[Screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn9J4.png)

[When no pictures have been added yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke0dw.jpg)

[First image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkNGX.jpg)

[Second image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djbOK.jpg)

I want to keep the images more center focused so they don't have the big gap between them

[Third image added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Rol.jpg)

Edit: 
Here is the HTML Code

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li class="active">Take Accident Photos</li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <h4>Vehicle I Photos</h4>
  <ion-buttons right>
    <button style="height:2.0em;" color="bground" ion-button icon-only (click)="getPicture()">
              <ion-icon  color="white" name="add"></ion-icon>
            </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-slides class="image-slider" loop="true" slidesPerView="5">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of veh1Image">
      <img src="{{img}}" class="thumb-img" imageViewer/>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
page-take-photo {

    ion-card-header {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }

    ion-card{
        height: 200px;
    }

    ion-scroll {
        height: 200px;
    }

ion-slide.swiper-slide {
    margin: auto;
    }

    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .slide-zoom {
        background: #e6e6e6;
    }

    .thumb-img {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .image-slider{
        height: 200px !important;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flex container to achieve a centered collections of items.
`display: flex;` on a container, with `justify-content; center` to center the flex items.

read more about flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is how I wrote it: https://imgur.com/a/7DCpS it doesn't seem to be working, its still coming out like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djbOK.jpg I'm not sure I wrote it out incorrectly.

Comment: can you post your code as an example instead of linking images